# How to auto-execute a SQL Script after starting a docker-compose sql instance?

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, ubuntu

After starting the docker container I have a ready sql5.7 server. But I need to create a root user with the name "root" and grant him all privileges and access from outside. So I need these sql commands to auto-execute after the container will be created.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql5.7
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'mypassword' 
    ports:
     - 33063:3306
    volumes:
      - sql-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  sql-data:
```

I need this sql commands auto-executed:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
CREATE LOGIN root WITH PASSWORD = "mypassword"
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES *.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a personalized image based on the original MySQL.
Create a folder and put the commands you need to run in there as a .sql and create a Docker file there, a simple file could be:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
COPY /NAME.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

This will make sure you create an image that is a copy of the original mysql 5.7 + your script. Then run a Docker run command in that folder to create an image and use that image name in place of the original mysql, example:

```
docker image build -t imageName:latest .
```